# Javascript create function from string

Tags: javascript, function, eval

I need to "parse"/create JS function from string. Lets say:

```
var str = "function(data,type,full,meta){ return'works';}";
```

I tried to use javascript *eval(str)* function but I always get this error from console when trying this

```
eval(str)
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

VM:2323:1

I don't see anyting wrong with the syntax.

Comment: `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name` in console. It requires function name. syntax `function function_name(arg) {}`

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because there is nothing which forces it to be parsed as a function expression, so it's parsed as a function declaration.

And function declarations require a name. From [Function Definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13),

> ```
> FunctionDeclaration :
>   function Identifier ( FormalParameterListopt ) { FunctionBody }
>
> FunctionExpression :
>   function Identifieropt ( FormalParameterListopt ) { FunctionBody }
> ```

An easy fix (if you are sure the string has a proper syntax) would be wrapping it in parentheses. Then it will be parsed as a function expression.

```js
eval('(' + str + ')')
```